# Why is a Hilbert space defined to be separable and complete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was studying Hilbert spaces to understand quantum mechanics, and I came across these two properties of such vector spaces. I couldn't understand how these two properties are useful in quantum mechaincs.